# How can I get to roll more dice in CthulhuTech?

Tags: cthulhutech

CthulhuTech runs on Framewerk, a system based on rolling several d10 and seeing if the result has a straight (at least three consecutive number) or three of a kind (or more); otherwise you go with the single highest number. This number is then added to your attribute to determine your result.

This means that rolling high is not automatically better than rolling low (rolling 10, 10, 8, 8 is worse than rolling 8, 7, 6, 5), so it is more desirable to roll as many dice as possible to get the biggest chance to get a good number.

However, from what I understand you only get to roll a very limited number of dice. If I read the book correctly the highest number of dice you can get for a single regular skill test is eight: five from your skill itself, one from a focus and two from a specialization. The downside is that those last three dice only apply if your focus and specialization are being met, otherwise you're stuck with your regular old five. And that's at the highest possible level for your skill: for a starting character this is far lower.

So I was wondering if there were other ways to get more dice to roll for tests. Preferably in a way where I do not have to rely on party members or situational differences like with the focus and specialization.

Answer (score 2):

### Drama Points

Each time your character uses a **Drama Point**, you are allowed to roll another dice on your check.

> Drama Points are used to manipulate a Character’s dice – any Character’s dice. For each Drama Point spent you can increase your Character’s number of dice for a Test by one, increase an ally’s dice by one, or rob an enemy of one of his Test dice.

This is the only way (in the core book), to roll more dice on a check.